# Get hidden elements webpage data from VBA code

Tags: html, excel, vba

Please help me on this issue. I am trying to get hidden texts from webpage with VBA. Unable to find solution.

Code:

Basic InformationBirthday14 July 2002 -->

I want to get texts of code id u_0_4e.
Output will be:
Basic Information</span></div>Birthday</span></div>14 July 2002</span></div></div></div></div></li></ul></div> -->

Comment: <div class="hidden_elem"><code id="u_0_4e"><!-- <div class="_4qm1"><div class="clearfix _h71"><span role="heading" aria-level="5" class="_h72 lfloat _ohe _50f7">Basic Information</span></div><ul class="uiList fbProfileEditExperiences _4kg _4ks"><li class="_3pw9 _2pi4 _2ge8 _4vs2" data-privacy-fbid="8787510733"><div class="clearfix _ikh"><div class="_4bl7 _3xdi _52ju"><span role="heading" aria-level="6" class="_50f4 _5kx5">Birthday</span></div><div class="_4bl7 _pt5"><div class="clearfix"><div><span class="_2iem">14 July 2002</span></div></div></div></div></li></ul></div> --></code></div>

Comment: I had tried this code but no help: Set oHtml = New HTMLDocument

On Error GoTo mmm

With CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", myURL, False
     .send
    oHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With
Set dados = oHtml.getElementsByClassName("hidden_elem")(0).getElementsByTagName("u_0_4c")

i = 0
For Each oElement In dados
    Sheets("Data").Range("A" & i + 1) = dados(i).innerText
    i = i + 1
Next oElement

Comment: where is the code? did you parse the html?

Comment: Please [edit] the code into the question (then select it all and press Ctrl+K to format as a code block)

Comment: Also, is there a source url you can share?